# Transfer data between EditText and Text View

Tags: android, textview, android-edittext, runtimeexception

I'm trying to make an activity that take the value of the EditText and put it in the TextView in another activity.

This is the code for the first activity which contains a Textview and option menu to edit it

```
public class Saturday extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.saturday);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String txt = i.getExtras().getString("txtData","");
    final TextView Tclass1;
    Tclass1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seven);
    Tclass1.setText(txt);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.saturday, menu);
    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
 switch(item.getItemId())
 {
 case R.menu.saturday:
     edit_schedule();
  return true;
 }
 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
public void edit_schedule() {
    final TextView Tclass1;
    Tclass1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.seven); 
    Intent i = new Intent(this, EditSaturday.class);
 i.putExtra("text" , Tclass1.getText().toString());
 startActivity(i);

}}
```

This is the code for the other activity which contains an EditText with the save button

```
public class EditSaturday extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.edit_saturday);

    Intent i = getIntent();
    String txt = i.getExtras().getString("txtData","");
    final EditText Eclass1;
    Eclass1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eseven);
    Eclass1.setText(txt);

    findViewById(R.id.save).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            save();
            }});

}

public void save() {
    final EditText Eclass1;
    Eclass1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.eseven);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, Saturday.class);
     i.putExtra("text" , Eclass1.getText().toString());
 startActivity(i);

}}
```

After I run the application it give me an error

this is the logCat

```
04-14 08:15:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1202): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-14 08:15:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1202): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{sarah.bodoor.sto/sarah.bodoor.sto.Saturday}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 08:15:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1202):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
04-14 08:15:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1202):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
04-14 08:15:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1202):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
04-14 08:15:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1202):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
04-14 08:15:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1202):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-14 08:15:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1202):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-14 08:15:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1202):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
04-14 08:15:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1202):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-14 08:15:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1202):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-14 08:15:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1202):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
04-14 08:15:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1202):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
04-14 08:15:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1202):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-14 08:15:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1202): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-14 08:15:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1202):     at sarah.bodoor.sto.Saturday.onCreate(Saturday.java:22)
04-14 08:15:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1202):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
04-14 08:15:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1202):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
04-14 08:15:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1202):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
04-14 08:15:17.911: E/AndroidRuntime(1202):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, Saturday.class);
```

should be

```
Intent i = new Intent(EditSaturday.this, Saturday.class); 
// should be referring to activity context
```

in your save()

Also

```
   i.putExtra("text" , Eclass1.getText().toString());// key in EditSaturday 
   // keys should be the same 
   String txt = i.getExtras().getString("txtData","");// key in saturday
   // keys are different
```

In your first activity get the editext value on button click and use intents to pass data between activities

```
EditText et= (EditText)findviewById(R.id.edittext);
String s= et.getText().toString();
Intent i= new Intent(firstActivity.this,secondActivity.class);
i.putExtra("key",s);
startActivity(i);
```

In your second actiivty onCreate()

```
setContentView(R.layout.second); 
Bundle extras= getIntent().getExtras();
if(extras!=null)
{
  TextView tv= (TextView)findviewById(R.id.textView1);
  String value = extras.getString("key");
  tv.setText(value); 
}
```

Comment: It works! that error gone. but now when I click the item from the option menu, the other activity doesn't start!

Comment: try Intent i = new Intent(Saturday.this, EditSaturday.class); You should refer to your activity context. R u getting nullpointerexception?

Comment: Yes I changed that. Now I don't get nullpointerexception but when I click on the item from the option menu, the other activity doesn't start

Answer (score 0):

try to implement this code.

```
String txt = i.getExtras().getString("text","");
```

replace with

```
String txt = i.getExtras().getString("txtData","");
```

because you required same key for get value from passing intent.

you put key "text" when pass intent and use key "txtData" when get that intent that both are different so, use same key foe passing and getting.

after you use following code for call next activity by option menu click.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
    menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Next");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
 switch(item.getItemId())
 {
 case 0:
     edit_schedule();
         return true;
 }
 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

}
```

Comment: nice i failed to notice the mistake. I edited my answer based on your answer. Although i gave a example which has the same key i failed to notice the same in the post.

Comment: It works! that error gone. but now when I click the item from the option menu, the other activity doesn't start!

Comment: I had another problem . sorry about that. my program is now working probably. BUT the activity Saturday should back to another main activity. but now it backs to the EditSaturday activity without clicking on the option menu.

Comment: i can't understand what u told me? so, please say about your flow of this tutorial and after u told me what is problem u faced?